# Read timed out Error builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1) - Flutter - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter, gradlew, flutter-dependencies

I am just trying to run my first flutter app.

I have already tried Invalidating Cache. Although my internet is slow, manually I have already downloaded the dependencies in less than a minute. But I am unable to install the dependencies manually.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on XT1080 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Abuzar\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app3\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.2.1/builder-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Read timed out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18m 48s
  Command: C:\Users\Abuzar\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app3\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Can I add this builder-3.2.1 dependency manually or any other fix for this problem? If yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.. i fix it by upgrading gradle.. with these steps:

- open **gradle-wrapper.propitiates** (if you can't find it open **gradle > local propitiates** Then click on **Open for editing in android studio** you will find **gradle-wrapper.propitiates** there.
- Change distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/**gradle-4.10.8-all.zip** **to** distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/**gradle-X.X.X-all.zip** according to the latest gradle version.
- then open **File > project structure > project > android gradle plugin version (change it to X.X.X)** according to the latest combatable gradle plugin version  .